# HTML load two urls in two frames in one page

Tags: html, frames

it is simple enough as an idea but i never tried it and attempted with the following code:

```
<html>
  <frameset cols="30%,70%">
  <frame src="www.google.com" name="frame1">
  <frame src="www.yahoo.com" name="frame2">
  </frameset>
</html>
```

example what am trying to load is google.com and yahoo.com in one page in two different frames. Any idea how?
Thanks,

Comment: Do not forget to mark answer as accpeted if it work for you

Answer (score 1):

use iframes!

```
<iframe src="url" alt="circa1990browser" />
<iframe src="url2" alt="circa1990browser" />
```

but i agree with the poster below. what you posted is technically correct and should work, as far as i know...

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has depreciated the use of `frameset` and `frame` tags.
Browsers like Google Chrome (which are widely used) are switching completely to HTML5.
Hence, using `frameset` and `frame` tags for public apps would be dangerous.

About the question:

The pages you are trying to load i.e. `Yahoo` and `Google` do not allow that by their X-frame-options.

So, it is virtually impossible now.

Answer (score 0):

Thats its its will work for you....is there any error in that ? Accorcing to me this will work fine.

Check this W3C site for more details : [Frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html)

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old question, but I believe I have the answer for you.

I believe google and yahoo have some sort of JavaScript running on their pages that detects whether they are being loaded in a frame, and if so, do not display any content.

In other words, your code is technically valid, but Yahoo and Google are explicitly preventing this action.

See this [JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JfQ6A/). The Yahoo and Google frames do not work, but the Craigslist one does.

(Note that I used `iframes` rather than a `frameset`, but the end result will be the same.)

Comment: is there any alternative for this ??? as i need to design a single page for facebook , twitter and instagram and all of them block the frames

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that were a violation of the ToS of those sites even if you could get around these restrictions.

All of those sites do publish APIs though, and have widgets you can embed, etc... These features will allow you to Integrate with those sites, but you will not likely be able to actually embed them.